# How to fix height respective screen resolution?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, height

I have posted Image of my webpage and also posted html code and CSS which I apply on it.

I want that my #main should display with fixed height on the page as a respective laptop resolution. 
So how much size should I give it?
 Another issue I'm getting is that, when I try to give height to it, it does not apply. My #main contains a footer too. 
What changes do I need to apply this in my css? My #main expands in height when I load any content in it. But I want that its height should be fixed.

[image]

***HTML***

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Index </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/Site.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.js">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/menu.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/menu.js">
</head>

<body>
<div class="page">
     <header>
        <table id="header">
        <div id="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
        <li class="current">
        <li>
        <a href="/CRMDashboard/Dashboard">
        </li>
        <li>
        <a class="parent" href="/CRM/Index">
        <div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a class="parent" href="#">
        <div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a class="parent" href="#">
        <div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/FilterCRMRequest/Index">
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
        </li>
        <li class="back" style="left: 30px; width: 100px; display: block; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="left"></div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
<section id="main">
    <h2>Index</h2>
        <footer>
                <hr>
                <p> Copyright (c) 2012 </p>
                <hr>
        </footer>
</section>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 117, 149, 0.9);
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.page {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 98%;
}

header, #header {
    border: 0 none;
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
header, footer, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

header, #header {
    color: #000000;
}

#main {
     padding: 30px 30px 15px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
top:50px;
bottom:10px;
/*position:fixed;*/
right:10px;
left:10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;

}
footer, #footer {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

***CSS For menu***

```
div#menu {
    background: url("images/main-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 41px;
}


div#menu ul.menu {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
div#menu ul {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#menu li {
    background: url("images/main-delimiter.png") no-repeat scroll 98% 4px transparent;
}
div#menu li {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

**I want output like this:**

[image]

**I also want that my #main display scroll bar when content load more ... rather than scroll bar display of browser.**

***these are my menus:***

[image]

**I can solve out problem by using `position:fixed` in #main but when I use it .. My #main gets overwrite on menus.**

[image]

Comment: The `header` tag hasn't been closed and your question isn't very clear. Please update the question and the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should'nt apply static height/ or give fixed height to it, although you can do it using javascript/jquery From the image you posted, i guess following css should be your solution.

Added css to your #main

```
  top:50px;
    bottom:10px;
    position:fixed;
    right:10px;
    left:10px;
```

Edit: Added `overflow:auto` in `#main`
**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/hEGms/2/

Comment: If I load any content.. I want Scroll display in #main rather than scroll of browser ! Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible. Loading any content causing overflow in your #main will add scrollbar in your #main itself, not in browser. That's why added overflow:auto in your #main

Comment: If i add position:fixed; .. layout gets messup.. means.. everything overwrite on menu bar. !! :(

Comment: can i have your complete code? Please add a fiddle for that so that i can help you.

Comment: I have edited my post. And I post menu CSS and layout CSS both. And after applying you changes I am not getting expected output. :(

Comment: I have edited my post. I also use different CSS for menu and different for layout. So I posted both. If i fixed possition:fixed. My #main overwrite menu  CSS

Comment: pardon me, but i still cannot create the menu bar from the code you posted. Until and unless i cannot see the menu bar i wont be able to solve the problem. I came up with this solution with your code but i am sure it is not complete http://jsfiddle.net/hEGms/5/

Comment: please add all the dom elements i.e the buttons, captions or create a fiddle yourself. In that way it will be easier to solve the problem

Comment: i guess the problem is the #main is overriding the menu due to its positioning. try to increase the top to 115px under the #main css

Answer (score 1):

From the w3c specification:

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content, typically with a heading.
>
> Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a
>   tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web site's
>   home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news
>   items, and contact information.
>
> ...
>
> Note: The section element is not a generic container element. When an
>   element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A
>   general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the
>   element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's
>   outline.

By this logic, if you need an element to apply styles to, you need a div. The `<section>` tag is a semantic tag and not a functional one. Inside your section tag you should have a div element holding the content and it should be the target for CSS styling.

**EDIT:** Also, since `<section>` is an HTML5 element, if you are using older browsers, you need to set it to `display: block` explicitly.

Comment: ohk I change this from <section> to <div>.

Answer (score 1):

on newer browsers you can set the height of your section dinamycally using the `calc()` function, e.g.

```
html, body, .page { 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
}

section {
   height: -webkit-calc(100% - 110px);
   height: -moz-calc(100% - 110px);
   height: calc(100% - 110px);
   border: 1px red solid;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Example dabblet: http://dabblet.com/gist/5308785

Browser supporting calc(): http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 0):

google for "Fluid Height Layout". you'll get many examples.

This [example](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/3284213/7aa86561e18cb5ff9d1ba5ddc255e07591301165) achieves what you are asking for.

Here's one [more](http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/superstretch-a-vertically-fluid-layout-using-css/)